# Android service to check internet connectivity?

Tags: android

I want to create an Android service, which notifies the main activity whenever disconnects and when internet reconnects again. I have following function for checking internet connectivity:.

```
private boolean haveInternet(){
        NetworkInfo info=(NetworkInfo)((ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(info==null || !info.isConnected()){
            return false;
        }
        if(info.isRoaming()){
            //here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to disable internet while roaming, just return false
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But I want to know, how to use it in a service.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Services are designed for long backgroud running task.
You should use a `BroadcastReceiver`:

This is a sample method I use to monitor the network state into my main Activity:

```
private void installListener() {

        if (broadcastReceiver == null) {

            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) extras
                            .getParcelable("networkInfo");

                    State state = info.getState();
                    Log.d("InternalBroadcastReceiver", info.toString() + " "
                            + state.toString());

                    if (state == State.CONNECTED) {

                        onNetworkUp();

                    } else {

                        onNetworkDown();

                    }

                }
            };

            final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
    }
```

Remember to call unregisterReceiver when the onDestroy event occurs

Hope this help.

Comment: Brilliant answer! I love how you created a method, and added the onNetworkUp and Down callbacks

Comment: Im using this and works great but I would like to have this in a class or a listener. so I can use it in more then one activity but I want to avoid code repetition. What would be the proper way to do so ?

Comment: hello, some help please ?

Comment: I added an answer with a class, as suggested by @NelsonSilva. I believe it's a starting point and we can continue to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Kotlin version**, following [Francesco Laurita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329692/francesco-laurita)'s solution:

```
private val broadcastReceiver by lazy {
    NetworkListener.create({
        btnOnlineVideos.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }, {
        btnOnlineVideos.visibility = View.GONE
    })
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    NetworkListener.register(this, broadcastReceiver)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    NetworkListener.unregister(this, broadcastReceiver)
}
```

For this to work I simply override the `onResume` and `onPause` methods, to register and unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`.

**How does this work?**

I created the following class that helps to initialize, register and unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`. That way there is no need to repeate most of the boilerplate code.

```
package com.programacionymas.app.services

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.NetworkInfo
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.util.Log

object NetworkListener {

    fun create(onNetworkUp: () -> Unit, onNetworkDown: () -> Unit): BroadcastReceiver {
        return object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

                intent.extras?.getParcelable<Parcelable>("networkInfo")?.let {
                    val info = it as NetworkInfo
                    val state: NetworkInfo.State = info.state

                    Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", "$info $state")
                    if (state === NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        onNetworkUp()
                    } else {
                        onNetworkDown()
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    fun register(context: Context, broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver) {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
        context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    fun unregister(context: Context, broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
    }

}
```

---

In case you need to execute sentences only for one of the states, you can pass a `null` anonymous function too:

```
private val broadcastReceiver by lazy {
    NetworkListener.create(null, {
        toast(getString(R.string.check_your_internet))
        finish()
    })
}
```

And declare the parameters as optionals in the `create` method:

```
fun create(onNetworkUp: (()->Unit)?, onNetworkDown: (()->Unit)?): BroadcastReceiver {/* ... */}
```

As well as invoking the functions only if they were sent as arguments:

```
if (state === NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
    onNetworkUp?.invoke()
} else {
    onNetworkDown?.invoke()
}
```

Comment: `NetworkInfo` is deprecated on Android 10+. You should update the implementation to use [`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)