# Detect broken internet connection whenever the application is running

Tags: android

I'm already using the code below to detect if the user is connected to the internet at the application's splash screen, but I need to detect this whenever the user is in a specific activity. Imagine you are using turn-by-turn navigation and you depend on internet connection, so you must detect a broken internet connection when it happens.

How can I do this without slowing down the app with an infinite loop?

```
private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot the code ;)

Comment: Nice Code but Where it is BTW :$

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Comment: I will add the missing code when I get home. Sorry about it.

Comment: @Juliano Nunes Silva Oliveira have you tried with the posted solution?

Comment: @PratikSharma not yet, but I'm gonna try it tommorrow and mark which one is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `BroadcastReceiver` do to so:

Here are few references for this you can get better idea about this with example.

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3142590/556975)

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350511/556975)

[Reference 3](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.in/2012/04/check-network-connection-using.html)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I belive you shoul write your own service with [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html), you should implement this method `public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {}` And from this service you can check in any time if there is DataConection.

Here is an article about [Android PhoneStateListener Illustration–with Auto Logging Calls to Google Calendar Example](http://www.roman10.net/android-phonestatelistener-illustrationwith-auto-logging-calls-to-google-calendar-example/)