# Should I check connectivity in every activity in Android?

Tags: android, connectivity

So I just implemented a checking connectivity method, but should I do this for every activity?  Is there a simpler way to continually check for connectivity?

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    return isConnected;
}
```

Comment: show us the code of your method

Comment: You should check connectivity every time you actually need it. Every time before you perform a request or anything similar. There is no way around that. If you fail to perform a check you app may crash or start behaving weird. Both don't make for a good user experience.

Answer (score 3):

First create a `ConnectivityChangeReceiver` like the following:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private OnConnectivityChangedListener listener;

    public ConnectivityChangeReceiver(OnConnectivityChangedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();  
        listener.onConnectivityChanged(isConnected);
    }

    public interface OnConnectivityChangedListener {
        void onConnectivityChanged(boolean isConnected);
    }
}
```

Then create a `BaseActivity` which extends all of your activites:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnConnectivityChangedListener {

    private ConnectivityChangeReceiver connectivityChangeReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        connectivityChangeReceiver = new ConnectivityChangeReceiver(this);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        registerReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectivityChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        // TODO handle connectivity change
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(connectivityChangeReceiver);
    }
}
```

(If you don't want a `BaseActivity`, you can implement `OnConnectivityChangedListener` in all of your activities. But in that case you have to register the receiver in all of your `Activity`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should check before every request to the internet! The user can terminate the connection at any given time... even while your Activity is running.

I suggest you make an `Utils` class and put this method inside and make it public static so you can access it from everywhere within the `Application`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this out: This is service that will continuously check the connection. This will be the proper way to do it

`private void installListener() {

```
    if (broadcastReceiver == null) {

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) extras
                        .getParcelable("networkInfo");

                State state = info.getState();
                Log.d("InternalBroadcastReceiver", info.toString() + " "
                        + state.toString());

                if (state == State.CONNECTED) {

                    onNetworkUp();

                } else {

                    onNetworkDown();

                }

            }
        };

        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
}`
```

Look on this link: [Android service to check internet connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141807/android-service-to-check-internet-connectivity)

Answer (score 1):

Create some sort of util class, for example `ConnectionUtils`.

Add a `public static` method to that class and add a `Context` object to the parameters. For example:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    return isConnected;
}
```

Then in your `Activity` just call `ConnectionUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)` to know if you're connected.

It would even be better to create some sort of base `Activity` that you extend with this method in it.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected boolean isConnected() {
         return ConnectionUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this);
    }
}
```

And then let all your `Activities` extend `BaseActivity` instead of `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

I say it is better to check before every request. It might happen that the connection got broken in between. So its not wise to rely on a check sometime earlier